# How to use the gems of Ruby 2.1 in Ruby 1.9 in batch

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.1

I have both Ruby 1.9 and 2.1 installed in my computer. Now I am wanting to use several of the gems installed for Ruby 2.1 in Ruby 1.9. However, Ruby 1.9 can't find them.

I tried to solve this problem by setting the environmental variable RUBYLIB but since there were so many gems that needed to be used I can't do it one by one. Is there an easier way?

For example, one of the packages I would like to use in Ruby 1.9 is pango.

Its path is ~/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pango-2.2.0/

All of the packages installed for Ruby 2.1 can be found at  ~/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems

Thanks you.

Comment: Libraries? You mean, gems? Just install them for ruby 1.9 too

Comment: Yeah, by saying libraries I mean gems. The problem is that I don't have the right to install them for Ruby 1.9. Is there an alternative way to use them in Ruby 1.9 without installing all of them in Ruby 1.9?

Comment: I suggest reading up on [Ruby Version Manager](http://rvm.io) and [Bundler](http://bundler.io/v1.10/gemfile.html).

Comment: Install ruby 1.9 as a non-system ruby (using rbenv or whatever)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use a manager like **rvm** (https://rvm.io/) or **rbenv** (https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) to avoid manually configuring your environment. I use **rvm** even when I have only one Ruby version installed.

Comment: In addition to bundler, which can help manage installing gems for a specific version of ruby. http://bundler.io/v1.10/gemfile.html